# what approach to use for webservices and android?

Tags: android, web-services

I need an advice if you may. I want to use webservices in Android and so far i am very much confuzed of the path i shoudl follow. I understand that there are 2 ways...soap and rest.
Trying to use soap(no native implementations) with a third party jar, ksoap.. that was fun but does not work. After finding a jar that actually compiles, and trying with some code i found on google i found that some methods do not exist in that jar and did not work. 
Now I am trying to use Rest, found this project [here](https://github.com/TylerSmithNet/RESTclient-Android) and trying to get what they did here.
I worked once with webservices and using a wsdl url, and axis2 i managed to generate stub classes.
I am really confuzed now :) what is the best approach, what to use in android?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest using REST as it is light weight as compared to SOAP. Also people have reported lot of performance issues with libraries like kSoap.

If you still want to use SOAP create soap message on your own programmatically instead of using a library.

For JSON processing try using GSON library http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/

Comment: hmm...to add credentials to the HttpRequest using this is correct?  `Credentials credentials = new UsernamePasswordCredentials(
     "username", "pass");
   client.getParams().setParameter(ClientContext.CREDS_PROVIDER, credentials);` ?